# How can I update a table using an update statement generated as column data?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update

I have the following code:

```
SELECT 'UPDATE table3 ENTRYNAME = '''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5000),
 riv.description)+''''+' WHERE id = '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), e.ID)+';'  AS 
 Update_Statement
FROM table1 AS riv 
JOIN table2 AS e
ON riv.Code = e.Code
AND  riv.definitioncode  = 'RIV'
AND riv.Description <> e.Description
AND riv.categoryID <> 0
;
```

This generates column values that look like this:

```
UPDATE table3 SET ENTRYNAME = 'new column data here' WHERE id = 50005;
```

I want to be able run the column data after it is generated.

How would I go about doing this?

Could it look something like this:

```
DECLARE @update_Statement --update statement

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT 'UPDATE table3 ENTRYNAME = '''+CONVERT(VARCHAR(5000),
riv.description)+''''+' WHERE id = '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), e.ID)+';'  AS 
Update_Statement
FROM table1 AS riv 
JOIN table2 AS e
ON riv.Code = e.Code
AND  riv.definitioncode  = 'RIV'
AND riv.Description <> e.Description
AND riv.categoryID <> 0

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @update_statement

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
EXECUTE @update_statement
END
CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: You could do a `UPDATE FROM`-statement.. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/04/30/sql-server-update-from-select-statement-using-join-in-update-statement-multiple-tables-in-update-statement/

Comment: I want to use T-SQL to run the generated UPDATE statements.  A solution of that manner would work for other similar but more complicated issues.

Comment: Then I suggest you look into `sp_executesql` and cursors. Create a cursor for your query, and then run `sp_executesql` with your generated queries. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/ http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx